# Unable to submit changes in feature layer using applyEdits arcgis for android

Tags: feature-layer, arcgis-android, arcgis-portal

After fetched my webmap from portal and found the layer I want add a polyline to, I'm trying to use the `applyEdits` method to update it in portal. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

My code goes as follows:

```
    Pesticide pesticide = globals.getPesticide();
    Map <String,Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    attributes.put("Name",pesticide.getAgricName());
    attributes.put("FarmeName",pesticide.getSiteName());
    attributes.put("CropType",pesticide.getCropType());
    attributes.put("ParcelID ", pesticide.getSiteID());
    attributes.put("PesticideType ", pesticide.getPestType());

    pestLayer = globals.getWebMapLayer();
    graphic = new Graphic (polyline, lineSymbol,attributes,0);

   Graphic [] adds = {graphic};

    ArcGISFeatureLayer featureLayer = new ArcGISFeatureLayer(pestLayer.getUrl(), ArcGISFeatureLayer.MODE.SNAPSHOT);
   if(featureLayer.isAllowGeometryUpdates()) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "all geometries are able to update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   else{
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "all geometries are NOTTTTTTT able to update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

    featureLayer.applyEdits(adds, null, null, new CallbackListener<FeatureEditResult[][]>() {

        @Override
        public void onCallback(FeatureEditResult[][] featureEditResults) {
            if (featureEditResults[0] != null && featureEditResults[0][0] != null && featureEditResults[0][0].isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Is Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE Mayuni! Could you please copy/paste the actual code into the question instead of providing a screenshot of the code? That way, it's more readable and people can test it by copying the code without having to write it =)